# Why celery task don't work?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

In my Django project I need to run celery task periodically. I use Celery 4 + Redis.

First I run `redis-server`, then use next commands:

```
$ celery -A TestProject worker -l info
$ celery -A TestProject beat -l info
```

First command raise next error:

```
The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[], {}, {"errbacks": null, "chord": null, "chain": null, "callbacks": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/enjoy_jumping/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 557, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'profile.tasks.amount_counting'
```

**celery.py** (file in the same directory as `settings.py` file)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'TestProject.settings')

app = Celery('TestProject')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**init.py:** (file in the same directory as `settings.py` file)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**settings.py:**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Almaty'

# Other Celery settings
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'amount-counting': {
        'task': 'profile.tasks.amount_counting',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60), 
    }
}
```

**tasks.py:** (file in the `profile` app's folder)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task


@task()
def amount_counting():
    # Code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution. I edit **celery.py** file:

```
import os
import sys
from celery import Celery
from celery._state import _set_current_app
import django
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'TestProject.settings')
app = Celery('TestProject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
_set_current_app(app)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../TestProject')))
django.setup()
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```